# Magsafe-2 car charger for 2015 MacBook Pro?

Tags: charging, magsafe

Is there such a thing as a Magsafe 2 charging cable that can be used from a car's 12V power outlet (UK).

This is for a 2015 MacBook Pro.

Thanks

Comment: What research have you done to find this out for yourself?

Comment: @IconDaemon I've looked at power inverters but that just seems a bit too over the top for my requirements - DC > AC > DC, surely there must be something simpler?

Comment: Perhaps there aren't any such devices on the market.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find this kind of product a few years ago. I could not find anything relevant. Nowadays, no more luck.

An inverter may be the only solution, although it may not be the best for you.

There are also integrated battery+inverter products like [GoalZero Yeti](https://www.goalzero.com/shop/portable-power/goal-zero-yeti-200x/) but it may be too expensive or "over the top" depending on your needs.